# Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key NavigationPaneButton

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, resourcedictionary

I am trying to reference the NavigationPaneButton resource in my styles.xaml. I've defined them all in different resource files and linked them all properly in the app.xaml with the right order. But I still get the exception

> "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key NavigationPaneButton"

Is there something I am missing?

```
<ResourceDictionary
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="WasHamburguerButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationPaneButton}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationPaneText}"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I've defined the resource in AppTheme.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationPaneText" Color="{ThemeResource NavigationPaneTextColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationPaneButton" Color="{ThemeResource NavigationPaneButtonColor}"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the color in AppColor.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
            <Color x:Key="NavigationPaneTextColor">#ffffff</Color>
            <Color x:Key="NavigationPaneButtonColor">#D13438</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is my app.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="WindowsUniversalApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:WindowsUniversalApp">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/AppColors.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/AppTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if you link them like this:

Styles -> AppTheme -> AppColors

So, AppTheme knows about AppColors:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestImage.Resources">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Resources/AppColors.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationPaneText" Color="{ThemeResource NavigationPaneTextColor}"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationPaneButton" Color="{ThemeResource NavigationPaneButtonColor}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And Styles knows about AppTheme:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestImage.Resources">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///Resources/AppTheme.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="WasHamburguerButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationPaneButton}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationPaneText}"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: That worked thanks :) Any reason why my solution wouldn't work?

Comment: Funny I just had this problem, but for the same app in a similar situation I didn't need to add MergedDictionaries in the single style files, in the app.xaml was enough